# Need some help understanding how to add an instance of an existing item to an invoice

Tags: netsuite

I have a SSP script that is attempting to create an invoice for an existing customer with a fee determined by what they applied for. I've set up the fee items under the noninventory items and I have a query which successfully gets the internal ID of the desired item. Next the script attempts to create an invoice and in doing so I am attempting to add the existing item using the internal ID that I have found. The problem is I can't get my head around how this relates, the schema browser shows a field called itemlist which is of type InvoiceItemlist which is made up of invoiceItems.

I take that to mean that I'm working with a sublist but there isn't an invoiceitem sublist type so I'm assuming I'm working with items. So, I've tried various ways to create a new sublist record but most of the examples I can find are how to create a new sublist record where as I just want to instantiate one of the existing items. I've included the snippet of code with my current attempt which isn't working.

```
var recNewInvoice = nlapiCreateRecord('invoice', {recordmode:'dynamic'});
        recNewInvoice.setFieldValue('customform', '104');
        recNewInvoice.setFieldValue('entity', stCustId);
        // Add Item to invoice
        _AddItem(recNewInvoice, stFeeId);
        if (stDiscountId) {
            _AddItem(recNewInvoice, stDiscountId);
        }
        try {
            objDataResponse.Invoice.Id = nlapiSubmitRecord(recNewInvoice, true, true);
        }
        catch (ex) {
            throw nlapiCreateError('WRITE_FAILED','nlapiSubmitRecord for invoice failed.' + ex.message);
        }

// further down I define the function

function _AddItem(recInvoice, ItemID){
    recInvoice.selectNewLineItem('item');
    recInvoice.setCurrentLineItemValue('item','item',ItemID);
    recInvoice.setCurrentLineItemValue('item','quantity',1);
    recInvoice.commitLineItem('item', false);    
};
```

I'm using a function for _AddItem because I'm may be adding a discount as well as the fee and I believe they are handled the same.  When I run the code with a test case that returns a valid stFeeId I get the following error in the SSP execution log:

nlapiSubmitRecord for invoice failed.Please choose an item to add

*edit added error

*edit: I've updated the code portion to show the changes I've made based on different resources I've found.  The original error isn't being generated but I'm getting this new error:

*nlapiSubmitRecord for invoice failed.Items you have requested in the record have been deleted since you retrieved the form*

Comment: What isn't working? You should be looking at the record browser; on the `invoice` record, there is a section for the sublist `item`.

From what I see here you're adding the item to the item sublist correctly.

Comment: The code when run returns the following error: "nlapiSubmitRecord for invoice failed.Please choose an item to add"  I am testing to make sure stFeeId is an actual value so going into the _AddItem function both variables are valid in my test case.

Comment: Are you missing adding a mandatory field to the line item? Try placing a try/catch in your `_AddItem` function.

Answer (score 0):

When facing a problem like this one, what I generally do is try to create the same record I'm trying to create using the script with the exact same values and by setting the fields exactly in the same order of the scripts.

I do this because, like in your case here, the order is crucial : when creating an invoice, setting the entity will impact what you can use in the other fields, including the Items : so if it is possible that you are trying to use Item1 with an EntityX and Item1 can't be chosen for that EntityX, so the item field will remain empty and you will get that error.

So try creating the Invoice from the UI and see if you can select your item after selecting your entity: if not, then you must fix your configuration, and once you are able to fully create your invoice from UI, you will be able to do so from Script.

Comment: That was a very good suggestion, I did try creating an invoice using the same role the script would run as and setting only the fields the script would set but I still get this error: nlapiSubmitRecord for invoice failed.Items you have requested in the record have been deleted since you retrieved the form

Comment: When you did it using the UI, were you able to select the Item you are trying to select in the Script ? I doubt, based on the error message, that the item is Inactive or Deleted : so when trying with the UI, you won't be able to select that item, and it will be the same using script.

Comment: I was able to select the desired item and the invoice was created successfully.  I made sure I was using the same customer ID and item ID as in my script.  I read that this error could be caused by the Chart of Accounts not being set up so I made sure the dev environment Chart of Accounts was up to date with what is in production.

Comment: If it is working on the UI then it must work on the script : so there must be something different between the two test : the fields order is also important. Maybe the groupsetup part is the culprit.